# Element refine incase of more than one in CSS selector

Tags: css-selectors

I have below code and the selector mentioned below gives two as it got the same id.

```
#grid-norecords > p
```

I tried with class name like :

`div[class="norecordmsg" #grid-norecords] > p` >> No results.

`#grid-norecords.norecordmsg > p` >> two results

So what's the best way to get the element with text "Unable to find any FX Contracts that match the details of this payment" as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked with parent class and id combination

```
.dialog-body #grid-norecords
```